# Deduction of some mathematical consequence from an inequality involving Ramanujan primes

Tags: number-theory, inequality, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

Adapting the solution in page 81 of [1] of  **Problem 1.69 (Amer. Math. Monthly)** for the sequence of Ramanujan primes $\{R_k\}_{k\geq 1}$ one deduces the following claim. Wikipedia has an article for [*Ramanujan primes.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan_prime)

**Claim.** *For any integer* $m\geq 1$ *there exists an integer* $N(m)$ *such that* $$\prod_{n=m}^{N(m)}(R_n+1)>2\prod_{n=m}^{N(m)}R_n\tag{1}$$
*holds.*

**Sketch of proof.** Just some companion details are that I've invoked the Theorem B-1 from Appendix B_1 of George Andrews, *Number Theory*, Dover Publications (1971), together the nature of the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty 1/R_k$ that is a consequence of a theorem due to Sondow (see [2]).$\square$

> **Question.** I wondered if one can to deduce some application (to get a more elaborated statement) from previous claim, that is from the inequality $(1)$. Can you get any consequence (with a good mathematical content) from previous inequality? **Many thanks.**

I tried to think some consequence for aliquot sequences, but without results.

### References:

[1] Valentin Boju and Louis Funar, *The Math Problems Notebook*, Birkhäuser (2007).

[2]  Jonathan Sondow, *Ramanujan primes and Bertrand's postulate*, Amer. Math. Monthly, 116 (7), pp. 630–635 (2009).